# Getting CumulusCI error "root path '/Users/.../.cci/snapshot' does not exist" when running command "cci task run list_changes --org dev"

Tags: cumulusci

I'm going through the "Build Applications with CumulusCI" Trailhead module. On the "Make and Capture Customizations to Your App" exercise, I made all of the requested changes to Salesforce (created the custom objects) and was then directed to show the list of my changes by typing the command "cci task run list_changes --org dev". I ran the command as instructed and received the error "'/Users/{MY_COMPUTER_USERNAME}/Documents/GitHub/Food-Bank/{MY_ORGANIZATION_NAME}/Documents/GitHub/Food-Bank/.cci/snapshot' does not exist".

I'm not really sure why CumulusCI is looking for the '../.cci/snapshot' folder in this location. The folder does exist. It's just not where CumulusCI is expecting it. The actual path to the folder is here: '/Users/{MY_COMPUTER_USERNAME}/Documents/GitHub/Food-Bank/.cci/snapshot', which is directly under the GitHub project root and where I would expect it to be. Any idea why CumulusCI is adding the extra '/{MY_ORGANIZATION_NAME}/Documents/GitHub/Food-Bank' to the path?

Comment: Mary, are you using GitHub Desktop or CLI GitHub or a mix of the two with your project?

Comment: @DavidReed, I used GitHub Desktop to set up this particular project.